# Connect to second router via external IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm trying to setup two routers in my home network, and I'm confused here.

[image: My system looks like this:]

I want to have access in Admin-Panel Router 2 from external (not in local network, but from mobile for example). 
I tried to write external IP, but in this way I open Admin-Panel in Router 1, witch I don't need.
Or my second try was xx.xx.xx.xx/192.168.xx.xx(external IP/local IP), but this do not work. 
 
So, how can I connect from external in Admin-Panel of Router 2, that is conected in Router 1(witch has internet with static IP)?
Thank you.

Comment: You're not being sufficiently clear.  You may have up to 3 IPv4 addresses involved, but your diagram doesn't show them.  You should have admin access from inside the network; having admin access via wireless is less secure and often you should disable that.  You did not include a question mark in your entire question, and we are unclear about what you are asking.  I guess you want to connect to the Admin of Router1.  There are different ways to do that; you should know your IPv4 addresses.  HTTP often works, but sometimes other approaches are used.  Check manuals.  Model #s may be helpful.

Comment: No, i want to have admin access from externat in Router 2. Something like Remote Management to Router 2.
But I dont' know witch IP to write in my browser, from work, for example, to access it.
If I write my static IP, witch is given by Internet Provider, I enter in Admin of Router 1, but I need Router 2

Comment: @romanbtc, that's probably not a very good idea. If you want to do that, I would recommend using a VPN tunnel. Have a login to get on the network, and the traffic is encrypted, then you need to login to Router2, once you are on the network. Usually, you want Router1 to support VPN access for this since you want to initiate it from the outside. Some routers have this support, and some don't.

Comment: @RonMaupin no, Router 1 have not support this.

Comment: That's the safe way to do it. You could forward a port to Router2, but that means anyone can try to attack Router2, and your traffic to your network is not encrypted.

Comment: @RonMaupin There is a problem, Router 1 is Internet Provider's router, and I do not have admin access to it, and can not do a port forward.

Is there other way?

Comment: The only other way is to initiate a connection from inside your network. You will not be able to initiate the connection from outside your network. One way is to use a VPN service where Router2, or some other device in your network which can forward traffic to Router2, connects to a VPN server on the Internet, and you can then connect to the VPN server from wherever you are.